# Set volume to 150% permanently and map volume keys from 0-150%

Tags: sound, keyboard, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I have a two fold issue since many years. I hope to find a fix now. I'm on ***Ubuntu Budgie 18.04*** and yet again the volume levels are very low.

1. Allow louder than 100% option is gone from the sound settings in *Ubuntu Budgie 18.04*. So I worked around it using `pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%`
2. Whenever I hit the volume up/down key, the volume resets to 100%. Then I will have to do `pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%` again to get louder volume from the speakers.

> How do I make, say **`150%` permanent** and map the **volume keys** to **work from`0-150%`**

Comment: You can look into editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.  I haven't used it before, so cannot offer any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.10 (cosmic) adds this feature by default. It works very nice too.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a setting called Over-Amplification in Settings > Sound. Turning it on and adjusting the volume slider above it will only get you to 100%, but you can still adjust beyond 100% by using either your keyboard's volume buttons if available, or adjusting the volume slider in the corner of your screen.

Comment: No such setting. Screenshots, if any ? Are you on an older version of Ubuntu ? Older versions had the slider you are referring to. And even they don't work with the volume UP key. Volume UP sends it to only 100% not the max.

Comment: Running 18.04, myself.  Second row: https://imgur.com/a/u6494de

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I'm on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04. Corrected that part in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

You can install pavucontrol, it let's me tune up to 153% on Ubuntu Gnome 18.04. There is also a setting in dconf `/com/ubuntu/sound` called 'allow-amplified-volume' but switching that true/false had no effect for me

Comment: The problem is pavucontrol works, but when I turn down the volume below 100% and then try to turn it back up it won't go beyond 100%. *Now that is the problem I am trying to solve*.